# Full-text index populate deadlock

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, deadlock

I have a large table with a full-text index. Sometimes I get deadlocks when reading data from this table.
Hypothesis: this occurs because the full-text index is updated slowly. But maybe there are some other reasons?

I found this topic, but this is not quite the case
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/248874/sql-server-full-text-population-deadlock

Deadlock body -

```
<deadlock-list>
    <deadlock victim="process1ddeb30f848">
        <process-list>
            <process id="process1ddeb30f848" taskpriority="20" logused="396"
waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 7 COMPRESSED_FRAGMENT(object_id =
388300543, fragment_id = 2072374), lockPartitionId = 0" waittime="4794"
ownerId="510063553054" transactionname="IFTSAutoNested"
lasttranstarted="2023-06-20T15:15:54.560" XDES="0x2a8dd78b210"
lockMode="Sch-M" schedulerid="54" kpid="18752" status="background"
spid="937" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2">
                <executionStack/>
                <inputbuf></inputbuf>
            </process>
            <process id="process33500aac4e8" taskpriority="0" logused="0"
waitresource="METADATA: database_id = 7 COMPRESSED_FRAGMENT(object_id =
388300543, fragment_id = 7665), lockPartitionId = 0" waittime="4794"
ownerId="510063553050" transactionname="FullTextCardEstimate"
lasttranstarted="2023-06-20T15:15:54.557" XDES="0x25274ba5a40"
lockMode="Sch-S" schedulerid="65" kpid="8740" status="suspended"
spid="543" sbid="2" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="1"
lastbatchstarted="2023-06-20T15:15:54.567"
lastbatchcompleted="2023-06-20T15:15:54.450"
lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.450" clientapp="WebApi"
hostname="APP3" hostpid="12345" loginname="User" isolationlevel="read
uncommitted (1)" xactid="510063552777" currentdb="7"
currentdbname="Prod" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672"
clientoption2="128056">
                <executionStack>
                    <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="344" stmtend="4332"
sqlhandle="0x02000000ff52a41a05b0e1854e7d1263870e1fcf727a58930000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
                    <frame procname="unknown" line="1"
sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
                </executionStack>
                <inputbuf>
SELECT [d].id    </inputbuf>
            </process>
        </process-list>
        <resource-list>
            <metadatalock subresource="COMPRESSED_FRAGMENT" classid="object_id =
388300543, fragment_id = 2072374" dbid="7" lockPartition="0"
id="lock3ac4fdb9180" mode="Sch-S">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process33500aac4e8" mode="Sch-S"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process1ddeb30f848" mode="Sch-M" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </metadatalock>
            <metadatalock subresource="COMPRESSED_FRAGMENT" classid="object_id =
388300543, fragment_id = 7665" dbid="7" lockPartition="0"
id="lock342d8e09180" mode="Sch-M">
                <owner-list>
                    <owner id="process1ddeb30f848" mode="Sch-M"/>
                </owner-list>
                <waiter-list>
                    <waiter id="process33500aac4e8" mode="Sch-S" requestType="wait"/>
                </waiter-list>
            </metadatalock>
        </resource-list>
    </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```